# how to use proguard in android for export apk

Tags: android, apk, obfuscation, proguard

what is '-injar' ?
what is mean?

Proguard returned with error code 1. See console

```
proguard.ParseException: Expecting class member name before '-injars' in argument number 7
at proguard.ConfigurationParser.readNextWord(ConfigurationParser.java:1133)
at proguard.ConfigurationParser.readNextWord(ConfigurationParser.java:1117)
at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseMemberSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:845)
at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:697)
at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseKeepClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:490)
at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:139)
at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:484)
```

I was add extenal library in proguard-project.txt
but cannot export apk.... How to slove it?

plz slove this problem....CodeObfuscation

Comment: Which Library you are trying to import? Also did you provided dontwarn arguments for package?  for example  -dontwarn android.support.v4.**

Comment: @Timson that's added /tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
where add that arguments ?

i'm add library like this in project proguard-projects.text
-keep class com.viewpagerindicator{*;}
-keep class com.kakao{*;}
-keep class com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib{*;}
-keep class android{*;}
-keep class com.kakao.exception{*;}
-keep class com.kakao.widget{*;}